# Problems with a chat program written in Python and PyGTK

Tags: python, pygtk, chatroom

I am new to python and I am currently working on a chat room program in Python (still in progress...). I have also made a GUI for my program. Initially, I made two py files, one for the GUI and one for the chatting function. They both worked perfectly when separated. After, I combined the two files. I faced the following two problems:

1. One of my threads (`target = loadMsg`) is used to wait for the host's msg and print it out on the screen. The problem is that it delays for one msg every time. For example, I sent a "1" to the host and the host should return a "1" immediately. But, the "1" I received didn't appear on my screen. Then I send a "2" to the host and the host should reply a "2" immediately. Then, my screen shows a "1" but the "2" is still missing until the host reply a "3" to me, after I send a "3" to the host. Where is the problem?
2. This is a technical problem. I was testing the stability of the chat room and I found that about 10% of my msg disappeared during the transmission and this situation occurs randomly. How can I fix such a problem?
      Sorry for my poor English. I hope someone can help me with it.T_T

Here is my code for your reference:
---Client

```
import pygtk,gtk
import logging
from threading import *
import socket

DEBUG = 1
HOST = ''
PORT = 8018
TIMEOUT = 5
BUF_SIZE = 1024

class Base():
    def reload(self):
        try:
            buf = self.sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
            print buf
            self.addMsg(buf)
        except:
            pass
    def reload_butt(self,widget):
        try:
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.reload)
            self.thread.start()
        except:
            pass

    def loadMsg(self):
        try:
            while True :
                    buf = self.sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
                print buf
                self.addMsg(buf)
            except:
                    self.sock.close()
    def sendMsg(self,widget):
        if DEBUG : print "Send Msg"
        if self.entry.get_text() : self.sock.send(self.entry.get_text())
            self.entry.set_text("")
    def addMsg(self,string):
        if DEBUG : print "Try to add Msg"
        if self.entry.get_text() :
            iter = self.buffer1.get_iter_at_offset(-1)
            self.buffer1.insert(iter,("\n Username: "+string))
            self.entry.set_text("")
            self.adj = self.scrolled_window.get_vadjustment()
            self.adj.set_value( self.adj.upper - self.adj.page_size )
            if DEBUG : print "Add msg ok"
    def destroy(self,widget):
        if DEBUG : print "Destroy function called"
        self.sock.close() 
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self,sock):
        if DEBUG : print "Initializing..."
        self.sock = sock

        self.win=gtk.Window()
        self.win.connect("destroy",self.destroy)

        self.vbox=gtk.VBox()
        self.win.add(self.vbox)

        self.view=gtk.TextView()
        self.view.set_editable(False)
        self.buffer1=self.view.get_buffer()

        self.scrolled_window=gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrolled_window.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC,gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
        self.scrolled_window.add(self.view)
        self.vbox.add(self.scrolled_window)

        self.entry=gtk.Entry()
        self.entry.connect("activate",self.sendMsg)

        self.enter=gtk.Button("Enter")
        self.enter.connect("clicked",self.sendMsg)

        self.reload=gtk.Button("Reload")
        self.reload.connect("clicked",self.reload_butt)

        self.hbox=gtk.HBox()
        self.hbox.add(self.entry)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.reload,False,False)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.enter,False,False)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox,False,False)

        self.win.show_all()
        if DEBUG : print "Finish initializing"
    def main(self):
        try :
            gtk.main()
        except :

            print "Error!!!"
def main() :
    try :
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT)) 
        print ('Connecting to '+ str(HOST) +' ' + str(PORT)) 
        base=Base(sock)
        thread1=Thread(target=base.loadMsg)
        thread2=Thread(target=base.main)
        thread2.start()
        thread1.start()
    except :
        print "Err0r!!!"
        sock.close()
main()
```

---host (an echo host)

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 8018


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)


conn, addr = s.accept() 
print 'Connected by', addr
try :
    print "Start!"
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
            print data
        reply = data # echo
        if not reply : break
            if reply== "!q" : 
                    conn.close()
            break   

        conn.send(reply)
    conn.close()
except :
    print "Error!!!!!"
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously recommend to use the gio library (part of glib). Using that library, you connect functions to the socket operations such as when data is available, or when data can be written to the socket. The library will call these function when necessary, and you don't need a wait loop. Which is more CPU-friendly.

http://jcoppens.com/soft/howto/gtk/chat_socket.php contains an example of communications between a C program and Python, using gio, which might be useful to you.

This way, you can start monitoring the sockets after the GUI has started, and you do not need threads to attend the communications.

Comment: Thz, I will go and have a look :)